# call a method one time from another method which have a CADisplayLink on it

Tags: iphone, xcode, frame, boolean, cadisplaylink

I would like to call from a method 'method1' another method 'method2'. The problem is that there is a CADisplayLink on 'method1' and when I want to call 'method2' from 'method1' it call it at 6Ofps so 60 times per second, but I just want that it call it one time. I know that I have to use BOOL variable but I don't know how to use them . Can anyone help me ? sorry for my english I'm french :/

//EDIT:
there is a CADisplayLink on method1:

```
-(void)method1{
if(
if ( leScore % 20000 == 0) {
[self method2];
```

}

```
-(void)method2{

etatJeu = arc4random() / (UINT_MAX/3);

switch(etatJeu) {
    case 0: /* top */
        etatJeu=kEtatJeu2;
        break;
    case 1: /* bottom */
        etatJeu=kEtatJeu3;              
        break;
    case 2: /* bottom */
        etatJeu=kEtatJeu4;              
        break;
    default:
        break;


}
```

so every time  'leScore % 20000 == 0' call one time method2.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the method call happen only once, then use a bool this way:

```
@interface SomeClass {
    BOOL method2RunFlag; // set to NO in init
}
@end

// ... in your method1

if( method2RunFlag == NO ) {
    // call your method2
    method2RunFlag = YES;
}
```

Based on your edited code above:

```
-(void)method1{
if( method2RunFlag == NO ) {
method2RunFlag = YES;
  if ( leScore % 20000 == 0) {
    [self method2];
  }
    // wait 1 second before able to call again
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(resetMethod2RunFlag:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
- (void)resetMethod2RunFlag:(NSTimer *)timer {
  method2RunFlag = NO;
}
```

Still not entirely sure what you're after but this is my best guess. =)

Comment: No not once because I would like to call it another time. And with your way I can't call it another time :/

Comment: If you want to call it again later on, you could set the BOOL to NO, and that would allow it to be run again.  Or perhaps I'm not understanding what you want to do exactly?

Comment: But how can I set it to NO.Because I set it to YES in the method. Do I have to put it to YES in the method after set it to NO

Comment: An alternative is to use a counter. Replace BOOL with an integer value that you increment every time method1 is called.  Then you can check to see if it's over (x) value, run method2 if it is, reset the counter to zero, and wait for it to be called again.

Comment: Humm it's a little bit hard for me can you explain more with a code please ?

Comment: Can you post some of your code here?  In particular the method signatures (as I've created above) and when you need to call them?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create 2 variations of method1, one to use with CADisplayLink, the other elsewhere, perhaps calling all the common code in a helper method1A, but with a flag parameter saying whether to call method2 or not.